# What tests and plots to use with conditional probability?

Tags: data-visualization, conditional-probability

I have datapoints collected from Italian students' curricula, including final marks received for one Exam (between 18 and 31) and their Final Degree (*cum-* or *sine-laude*).
I’m interested in studying whether the mark that students receive for Exam and the probability of the event ‘*graduating cum laude*’ are related. 
I thought that this can be studied using conditional probability. That is, I want to observe:

$P($graduating cum laude $ | $ Exam mark $ >= T)$

where $T$ is a threshold mark that I’m also interested in discovering.

Is this conceptualization correct? If so, what kind of statistical analysis and plot would you recommend as appropriate?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test about this probability? Do you want to test if the probability is above some value? Or do you want to test if marks and the probability are related?

Comment: Hi @gung : it's the second, if marks and the event of graduating cum laude are related. I'm fixing the question body too. Thanks